# How to write this basic sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have 4 tables that are connected via foreign keys namely result, position, student, candidates

What i need to achieve is this:
output:

```
------------------------
 s_fname | count(c_id)
-----------------------
   Mark  |     2       -> President
   France|     2       -> President
```

.. to count as to how many times a c_id have been repeated in the table "result" which is also filtered by pos_id from the "candidates" table

Below is my code which lacks the counting part:

```
select s_fname 
from results, candidates, student, positioning 
where results.c_id = candidates.c_id 
  AND student.sid = results.sid 
  AND candidates.pos_id = positioning.pos_id 
  AND positioning.pos_id = 1 
Group BY results.sid;
```

..which I know lacks a lot of things ...

Thanks

it seems very complex to me but i know there are gurus here who can achieve this,

result table

```
---------------------
| r_id | sid | c_id |
---------------------
    1   |  1  |   1
    2   |  1  |   2
    3   |  1  |   4
    4   |  2  |   1
    5   |  2  |   2
    6   |  2  |   4
    7   |  3  |   3
    8   |  3  |   2
    9   |  5  |   3
    10  |  5  |   2

----------------------
student table
----------------
| s_id| s_fname|
----------------
    1  |  Mark
    2  |  Jorge
    3  |  France
    4  |  James

--------------------
Candidates Table
------------------------
| c_id | sid  |  pos_id
------------------------
    1   |   1  |     1
    2   |   2  |     2
    3   |   4  |     3
    4   |   3  |     1
    5   |   5  |     2


----------------------
positioning Table
-----------------------
| pos_id  |  po_name |
-----------------------
 1    |  President
 2    |  Vice President
 3    |  Secretary
 4    |  Treasurer
```

Comment: I would help if you created a SQL fiddle and entered the data - then people could use it. Posting the data as plain text requires people to enter it manually...

Comment: @BoristheSpider True, but at least there is a text to ddl option on sql fiddle to make things easier.  At least they provided some data

Comment: @BoristheSpider http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9472a/20... given by sir maszter ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but should return your intended result.

What it does is joins all of your tables on the related `foreign keys`, effectively giving a wide table of all of your columns. Then we limit on the `candidates` that are running for the `President` position. Since we need to `group` because of the `count aggregate` we `group` on the `name`. The `count` should reflect the number of votes they got, because there is a `one to many relationship` to the `result` table.

```
SELECT s_fname, Count(*) 
FROM studentTable st 
INNER JOIN Candidates c On c.sid = st.s_ID 
INNER JOIN positioning p on c.pos_ID = p.pos_ID
INNER JOIN results r on st.s_ID = r.s_ID
WHERE po_Name = "President"
GROUP BY s_Fname
```

Due to a misunderstanding of the intended joins, the following query should show the appropriate results.

```
SELECT s_fname, Count(*) 
FROM studentTable st 
INNER JOIN Candidates c On c.sid = st.s_ID 
INNER JOIN positioning p on c.pos_ID = p.pos_ID
INNER JOIN results r on c.c_ID = r.c_ID
WHERE po_Name = "President"
GROUP BY s_Fname
```

Comment: strange ... the counting doesn't seem to be accurate also ... or is it just me?

Comment: @JustinAizengard Based on how it seems the IDs map, you have three records in the `results table` for Mark and 2 for France.

Comment: if I manually count the candidate id "1" which is "Mark" from the "results" I can only see 2 records, but based on the sql fiddle it counted "3" records..

Comment: @JustinAizengard I edited my answer. You should get the expected results now from the second query.

Answer (score 1):

## Code:

```
SELECT s_fname AS [Student Name], COUNT(A.c_id) AS [Count], po_name AS [Position]
FROM results AS A INNER JOIN candidates AS B ON A.c_id=B.c_id
                  INNER JOIN student AS C ON A.sid=C.sid
                  INNER JOIN positioning AS D ON B.pos_id=D.pos_id
WHERE B.pos_id = 1 
GROUP BY s_fname
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.s_fname, COUNT(*), p.po_name
    FROM students s 
    JOIN candidates c ON c.s_id = s.s_id
    JOIN positioning p ON c.pos_id = p.pos_id
    JOIN results r ON s.s_id = r.s_id
WHERE p.pos_id = 1
GROUP BY s.s_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9472a/17

Comment: strange ... the counting doesn't seem to be accurate ... or is it just me?

Comment: The counting is not accurate for this because it is counting from the wrong tables.  Why did you mark this one as the answer if it wasn't giving you the required output?

Comment: yes.. I chose the other one which is more accurate.